# Create an 'Out of Stock' Category

Tags: magento2, product-collection, category-products, out-of-stock

I am trying to create an category that displays all products on the website that are currently set as out of stock.

I have created a subcategory for this and thought that I would be able to modify the list.phtml file and apply afilter when getting the product collection however this file seems to use the following call `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();` This call doesn't seem to allow you to add any filters on to it.

I have searched and tried various methods to try and get and filter a product collection to no avail.

I am looking for a way to get every product set as out of stock, regardless of category, and display it in the category grid template is there a way to do this with `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();`?

Alternatively I've also considered the possibility of programmatically adding a product to the "out of stock" category when it goes out of stock and then removing it when it comes back in stock - if anyone has any experience or ideas on how this might be achieved then it would be helpful if you could share!

Thanks.